# Let's Encrypt certificate renewed, but the site delivers the old one

Tags: lets-encrypt

My https certificate(s) will expire in about one week and I ran the script to renew them.

They seem to be renewed, since if I try to run the `certbot-auto` again, it would show me some messages saying that the certificate expiration date should be closer to the today date.

The problem is that the website looks like it's still serving the old certificate. The expiration date is not changed.

Is this expected? How to force the renewal of the certificates?

Relevant output:

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect ionicabizau.net:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
notBefore=Aug 28 03:40:00 2016 GMT
notAfter=Nov 26 03:40:00 2016 GMT
```

The files on the server look updated:

```
$ ls
cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem
$ stat -c '%y' *
2016-11-17 06:03:20.838837999 +0000
2016-11-17 06:03:20.838837999 +0000
2016-11-17 06:03:20.838837999 +0000
2016-11-17 06:03:20.838837999 +0000
```

Comment: This command connects and tells you certificate expiry date: "echo | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates". What does it say? You can also find the renewed certificate on the drive and there's likely a way to get it to tell you it's expiry date, and you can see the last modified date on the file. Post all that information.

Comment: @Tim I've updated my question. Could it be that nginx somehow caches the certificates in memory or somewhere?

Comment: restart service (apache, nginx)

Comment: @alexus Yes, confirming that it fixed the issue. Thanks a lot! In my case I only did `sudo service nginx reload`. So, is nginx caching the certificates? How can I improve my cronjob to handle that? Simply by adding `sudo service nginx reload` after the renewal command?

Comment: yeah, you must reload service after renewing certificates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The web server deamons (apache, nginx, ...) only load the certificates when the configuration is loaded and keep them in memory while they are running. certbot provides some hook parameters that you can use to reload the daemon after a certificate is renewed.

Example [from the documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewing-certificates):

```
certbot renew --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"
```

Reloading the service with the post hook should suffice though. This is what I use:

```
certbot renew --deploy-hook "service nginx reload"
```

Of course you could just run `service nginx reload` after every run of certbot, but using the renew hook has the benefit that the daemon is only reloaded if certificates have actually been renewed.

Comment: On Apache, I would suggest using the apache2ctl `graceful` reload (however exactly that is done on any particular system). Doing so will keep any existing connections open, ensuring that service is not interrupted to current visitors.

Comment: is it `--deploy-hook` instead of `--renew-hook`?

Comment: Seems like the parameter was renamed since I wrote that answer. Thanks for the heads up, I updated the answer.