# How to automatically update an SSL certificate on Nginx as it gets renewed?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, godaddy, ssl-certificate-renewal

I have a website hosted on an EC2 instance with Ubuntu and nginx installed. My domain is managed through GoDaddy which is where I also issue the SSL certificate for the domain. Recently I got service disruption as the SSL certificate expired. The problem is that I have to watch the certificate expire and pair it with my nginx configuration, which causes service disruption. Is there any way for me to get this process done before it expires or completely automated?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let's Encrypt certificate renewed, but the site delivers the old one](https://serverfault.com/questions/815672/lets-encrypt-certificate-renewed-but-the-site-delivers-the-old-one)

Comment: Certbot recommends to run the cronjob to renew the certificate daily. It will only renew it when needed.

Comment: Using certbot seems like a solutioni. Thanks for pointing that out. I will give it a shot.

Comment: Oh, somehow I thought I read in your question that you were using Let's Encrypt. Sorry, my fault, if you don't then this is of course not really a solution.